# How to reduce EAR file size of ADF 12c

Tags: deployment, glassfish, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, ear

Im deploying an ADF Web Application for GlassFish. (https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/deploying_oracle_adf_applications_to) My application runs on Glassfish but the generated EAR is too big (100 Mbs), the application only have two jsf pages. Exploring the .war i have see that JDeveloper exports a lot of ADF Internal libraries.

Do you know if is it possible to reduce this size of the EAR?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ADF you need the ADF libraries - that's why your EAR is big.
It however won't grow at the same rate if you add more pages etc.

On WebLogic we use shared libraries for all the ADF libraries - which results in smaller EAR files.